# Fields are used like types C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is a basic method to store an array. However the following errors keep arising:

```
 The first error: TelephoneNumbers.TelephoneNumbersFileReader.inputFile is a field but
                   is used like a type
 The second error: System.IO.File.OpenText is a method but is used like a type




     namespace TelephoneNumbers
     {

     class TelephoneNumbersFileReader

     {
         public void storeArray();


         const int SIZE = 7;
         string [] AllPhoneDetails = new string [SIZE]; 

         int index = 0;

         StreamReader inputFile;

         inputFile = File.OpenText("TelephoneNumbers.txt")



     }

 }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: You probably won't get very far unless you actually write some valid code. Perhaps you should look at some examples of C# code.

Comment: You nedd to put some of that code in a method.

Answer (score 2):

- You can't declare a method like `public void storeArray();`. It can't have the `;`.
- The contents of that method need to be wrapped in `{`/`}`s.
- `inputFile = File.OpenText("TelephoneNumbers.txt")` needs a `;` at the end of the line.

Thus it becomes:

```
namespace TelephoneNumbers
{
    class TelephoneNumbersFileReader
    {
        public void storeArray()
        {
            const int SIZE = 7;
            string[] AllPhoneDetails = new string[SIZE];

            int index = 0;

            StreamReader inputFile;

            inputFile = File.OpenText("TelephoneNumbers.txt");
        }
    }
}
```